# Name of this type of real function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that there exists a real number $\mu$ such that $f\geq \mu>0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Please tell me is there any specific name of this type of function?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe "$f$ has a positive infimum"?

Comment: Besides what @Theo Bendit suggested, we could also call this a function that is bounded above zero on $\mathbb R.$